# Is there a way for me to create a loop so that if the item is not found, the driver refreshes and the browser refreshes aswell?

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
//looking for item
driver.findElements(By.css('.inner-article')).then((articleItems)=>{
articleItems.map((artItem)=>{
    artItem.getText().then((a)=>{
//checks for specific item matching color and product
if(a.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase()) && a.toLowerCase().includes(color.toLowerCase())){
                    artItem.click();
                    console.log("Adding item to cart...");
```

I need a loop so that it can refresh if the item is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag:

```
let found = false; // <--- flag
//looking for item
driver.findElements(By.css('.inner-article')).then((articleItems) => {
    articleItems.map((artItem) => {
        artItem.getText().then((a) => {
            //checks for specific item matching color and product
            if (a.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase()) && a.toLowerCase().includes(color.toLowerCase())) {
                found = true; // <--- se to true
                artItem.click();
                console.log("Adding item to cart...");


if (!found) { // create a condition
   // do whatever you want
}
```